# Existence of a proper birational morphism from a Gorenstein scheme, with trivial higher direct images, implies Cohen-Macaulay?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, birational-geometry, cohen-macaulay, gorenstein

Let $R$ be a Noetherian [excellent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring) reduced local ring containing a field of characteristic $0$. If there exists a [Gorenstein scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorenstein_scheme)
$Y$ and a proper birational map $f: Y \to \text{Spec}(R)$ such that $R^i f_* \mathcal O_Y=0, \forall i>0$, then is it true that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this standard or well-known? I would be happy with a reference ...

Comment: Gorenstein means locally Gorenstein for you?

Comment: @Mohan: locally Gorenstein and finite dimensional.

Comment: For future users (and for people who apparently did not find this question good enough) see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450239/proper-birational-morphism-from-a-gorenstein-normal-scheme-to-a-normal-local-dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R = \{f : f(0,0) = f(0,1)\} \subset k[x,y] = S.$

Then $\operatorname{Spec} R$ has a nodal singularity and isn’t Cohen-Macaulay since it looks like two 2-planes meeting at a point. $\operatorname{Spec} S$ is smooth of course, hence Gorenstein.

The map $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is proper and birational, and since the fibers are all zero-dimensional, the higher direct images vanish.

Comment: Do you have any counterexample where $R$ is normal ? Of course such a counterexample would have to be at least 3-dimensional, as 2-dimensional normal rings are Cohen-Macaulay

Comment: Hmm, so one relevant theorem is that normal + rational singularities implies CM. I’m not sure if your assumption implies rational singularities though.